# AngularJS - update scope when another scope value meets a greater than condition

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where I get a shopping cart subtotal and then add the shipping costs to have the total. First I select the quantity of items via a select ng-option that outputs the final price `subTotal` of the items

```
<select ng-options="item.totalprice as item.quantity for item in inventory" ng-model="subTotal"></select> 

  <p>Subtotal: {{subTotal}}$</p><br><br>
```

And then the shipping costs `shippingCosts` are selected via ng-options

```
<select ng-options="country.shipping as country.name for country in countries" ng-model="shippingCosts"></select> {{shippingCosts}}$<br><br>
```

Being the total the sum of both outputs:

```
<p>Total: {{subTotal + shippingCosts}}</p>
```

What I want to achieve is to set `shippingCosts` equal to zero when `subTotal > 500`. Here you can see a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GkW5Oa07A637WPKvbd4m?p=preview) Thanks in advance!

*I tried making a variable `shippingFinal` that would update when `subTotal > 500`, but it doesn't seem to work

```
if ($scope.subTotal >= 500) {
    $scope.shippingFinal = 0
} else{ 
    $scope.shippingFinal = $scope.shippingCosts
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-change for price `select`.
View:

```
<select ng-options="item.totalprice as item.quantity for item in inventory" ng-model="finalPrice" ng-change="adjustShippingCost()"></select>
```

In controller this might look like:

```
$scope.adjustShippingCost = function() {
  $scope.shippingCosts = $scope.finalPrice >= 500 ? 0 : $scope.shippingCosts;
};
```

Note that this will change the `shippingCosts` in one direction, i.e. you can still select them from the list. Solution here is to add `ng-change` for shipping, or disable, hide, etc the shipping `select` field.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS ONE CODE:

```
if ($scope.subTotal >= 500) {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
             $scope.shippingFinal = 0
        });
} else{ 
    $scope.shippingFinal = $scope.shippingCosts
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I don't get it to work. See updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nYwlaeJX0PI6vI6vRZ2y?p=preview